# Another game that I loved to play

Tags: riddle, video-games

I still have some games that I love to play, so here is another riddle about one.

> 1) X marks the first part of my name,
>
> but only if you change my angle by aim.
>
> Lastly comes what I shout,
>
> afterwards a rain of bullets comes out.
>
> 2) Now you know my host,
>
> but to you I'm still a ghost.
>
> They say that I'm unfair,
>
> where one has guns the other knows despair.
>
> False because they can't be seen,
>
> unless they move then you'll see what I mean.
>
> They say listening is my best skill,
>
> though those who can't be seen will never admit this when I kill.

What is the name of this online game, and which mode did I used to play?

HINT:

> 1) is about the name of the game itself. 2) is about my favorite mode in the game.

Comment: Ghost Games is a video game company

Comment: @Duck not what I'm looking for

Comment: Maybe give a hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the game is

> Crossfire (cross is a common symbol for a gun aim, and when you change the angle - rotate it, you get X)

and you would usually shout

> FIREEE! before shooting.

As for the mode, I believe you are referring to

> ghost mode

False because they can't be seen,
unless they move then you'll see what I mean

> This makes sense because in ghost mode, you are stealthy only when you're not moving or shooting. And you also flat-out referenced ghosts. :D

The mode might be wrong, since I haven't actually played the game.

Comment: DING DING DING we have a winner :p and yea I might have been a bit too obvious with the mode. But once you would have guessed the game, the mode wouldn't be so hard since there aren't many modes in the game.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Team Fortress 2?

1)

> Not entirely sure about this

2)

> This sounds like [Prop Hunt](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/PropHunt)

Comment: Nope not what I had in mind, though it is a fun game :p. (for others to read this, both game and mode are unfortunately incorrect).

Comment: #1 works for this answer. T is an X rotated, and if a bunch of bullets were coming at you or out of your own gun, you might shout "oooh"!